# can I run same thread for multiple times?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have code like:

```
while(1) {
     if(request == ACCEPT)
          pthread_create(&t1, NULL, test_thread, NULL);
}
```

and test_thread code is like

```
void *test_thread(void * arg)
{
       //never ending function
}
```

This working fine and didn't get any problem. But my question is there any problem if I run like this?

Comment: the only concern would be `//never ending function`... if you keep creating threads that never die, you'll end up running out of resources :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple threads with the same thread procedure. The only thing you have to worry about is the shared data (global/static variables, etc.).

Comment: If i want to ccommunicate with other threads in future, is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You'll have to share some data for that, among which some synchronization objects. Just use the latter carefully when accessing your shared data.

Comment: @SGG Be careful not to become too broad in your question or it will be closed for being off-topic.  If you want to learn about parallel programming, StackOverflow is not the site for you.  Search for a tutorial on this.  Asking for (pointers to) one also does not belong here.  We aren't Google.